# Issue in logging the spring @Async logger

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous, log4j

I have a Spring MVC application which runs on Tomcat. The service layer that I have created uses `@Async` annotation. I use log4j for logging. The issue that I have is that logs gets appended to `catalina.out` but not into the rolling file.

Sample code :

```
@Async
public Future<Boolean> processReq(...)
      LOGGER.info("Executing flow1 ");
return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(status);
```

Log4j :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CA, rollingFile

#Console Appender 
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#File Appender 
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=${deploy.dir}/logs/sample.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue to be in my import statement. The import statement has a different Logger configured than Log4j.